# MSSQL "connection reset by peer" on Azure using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

I currently have a web service which queries through Python/SQLAlchemy to an MSSQL DB hosted on Azure. Every now and then, I get a Net-Lib error with "connection reset by peer." At first I thought it was a timeout, but it didn't seem consistent, the error sometimes didn't occur even if I waited hours to invoke it again. What could this be?

Comment: I think on any cloud you should expect a small percentage of connectivity errors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589788.aspx

Comment: You can refer to the similar thread on SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095555/sqlalchemy-pymssql-connection-reset-by-peer-recovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joe,

There's a load balancer in Azure that has a default timeout of 4mins and will shut off idle connections. Some languages like node.js have a timeout of 2seconds while making client requests. There could be many other reasons for connection reset and below link has few [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms847613.aspx)
 on it.

About this issue, it is more of server(SQL) issue rather that client. I would suggest you open a service request via this link(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/)